# How to achieve glow effect apart from using flash

Tags: jquery, flash, menu

Is it possible to make a glow effect any other way then flash? 
I want to get rid of the whole flash menu and use something browser friendly.I am looking for alternatives or similar effect.
[My site](http://www.blackflow.pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do animated glow like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fgQDk/

I don't have the specs you used for flash so it looks different. Also, it won't work in IE. If you want it to work in IE either don't have flashy effects for those users (the css won't have any effect so you don't need to do any changes) or use flash.

You can get different effects by playing with the color and pixel values.

Comment: yes I was wondering about css3. Unfortunately, majority of my client use IE...still, I am leaning towards your suggestion. I am starting to see more and more pages which are nearly static for IE users and flashy for everybody else...everything beets using flash...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery glow seems pretty good.  http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-glow

Comment: To be honest, this looks pretty bad and works only on WebKit.

Comment: Didn't notice webkit-only, but it's not far off from the affect on the site posted.

Comment: thanks but it is...as you can see on the site, the glow is from the back which preserves text readability. I was hoping for a jquery solution because it could work on Ie..

Answer (score 0):

Using box-shadow and coloring it into something vibrant and light would make a nice glow effect.